# Google oAuth API 503

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, gmail-api

I have a service which requires the usage of refresh credential API from Gmail and I have recently noticed a surge in HTTP 503 errors for the following API: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token

This happens for a certain duration of times and twice it coincided with a gmail downtime according to Google App Status. I have also checked to make sure that any Quota limits for gmail API was not hit from the admin console.

Please advice on how to proceed further on this.

Editing the question to provide further details from comments:

There are separate limits on authentication API (like the token endpoint).
 
-- Where do I find the limits on authentication API in Google developer console? I could only find the limits for Application APIs like Gmail/Google Calendar.

Questions: 

How often are you calling this API/token endpoint?
 
-- once every ~50-60 mins for a user

Is this for the same user/token? (for the same user, you should try to use the access token until the expiry time that is 1 hour).
 
-- No this is for different users. For the same user, the same access token is used until its expiry.

If your server is making a lot of requests for different tokens/users, are they coming from the same IP? 
-- They are not coming from the same IP, but from few servers (~5) which makes these requests.

What is the max qps you may be hitting?
 
-- 300 qps on an average (aggregated from all our servers), max would be 450 qps.

Comment: The general guideline for 503 errors is to look for a `Retry-After`-header in the response. If there is no such header present, treat it like a 500 and keep on trying again (maybe with an exponential falloff?).

Comment: There are separate limits on authentication API (like the token endpoint).
Questions:
How often are you calling this API/token endpoint?
Is this for the same user/token? (for the same user, you should try to use the access token until the expiry time that is 1 hour). 
If your server is making a lot of requests for different tokens/users, are they coming from the same IP? What is the max qps you may be hitting?

Without knowing the details on how often are you seeing it and specifics on tokens, it is hard to give precise answers.

Comment: @nvnagr I have edited the question to provide further details.